# question about javascript string's replace method

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I know that I can pass a string as the second parameter to the JavaScript string object's replace method. In this case I can use ***$`*** and ***$'*** to reference the left/right part text of a successful match. Now my question is, If I pass a callback function as the second parameter, how can I get the same information? I want to use this infomation in the callback function. Great thanks.

Comment: ...whoa, you can use a callback? Neat!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Replace); you won't get that data for free.

The good news is, you *will* get the offset of the match as your second-to-last argument, and the total string as the last. So you can run your own substring functions.

```
var str = 'abc';
str = str.replace('b', function (match, offset, full) {
    var before = full.substr(0, offset),
        after = full.substr(offset + 1, full.length - offset);
    return 'foo'; // or, ya know, something actually using before and after
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'abc';
str = str.replace('b', function (match) {
    // (!) List of actual arguments depends from template of RegEx >>>
    var offset = arguments.length - 1, full = arguments[offset];
    offset = arguments[offset - 1];
    // (!) But the first argument is match
    var before = full.substr(0, offset),
        after = full.substr(offset + 1, full.length - offset);
    return 'foo'; // or, ya know, something actually using before and after
});
```